# Вывод контактных данных 1С-Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Возникла сложность с выводом контактных данных на сайте. У компании несколько филиалов, поэтому контактные данные хранятся в инфоблоке.

1. Имя филиала
2. Телефон
3. Адресс
4. По умолчанию

В хедере и футере сайта нужно вывести контактные данные по умолчанию. В хедере телефоны в футере адресс и телефон.

Каким образом не писать php код с обращением в инфоблок в шаблоне и при этом вывести данные в хедер и в футер?

P.S. думал использовать агенты или события, но они не возвращают данные в шаблон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте у инфоблока свойство "Филиал по умолчанию" типа список, немножественное, с одним значением (это будет выглядеть как галочка).

Для вывода используйте компонент news.list с фильтром по этому свойству. Это делается так - вы прописываете фильтр в глобальной переменной (перед вызовом компонента):

```
global $myFilter;
$myFilter = Array("!PROPERTY_myproperty"=>false); // Это означает - свойство с кодом myproperty установлено
```

После этого прописываете название вашей глобальной переменной в параметре компонента "FILTER_NAME":

```
"FILTER_NAME" => "myFilter",
```

Таким образом, компонент выведет только те элементы, у которых установлена галочка "Филиал по умолчанию". А чтобы не вывелось больше одного элемента, если случайно кто-то поставит галочку на нескольких, установите количество элементов для вывода - 1 в параметрах компонента.